# Create a MySQL Trigger with IF THEN ELSE Condition on a single column

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows

**tbl_1**

```
Id            Name                   Status              flag
===============================================================
1               ABC                      1                 0
2               XYZ                      0                 0
```

and audit table as

**tbl_audit**

```
autit_id       Id            Name                   Status              flag      audit_time_stamp      
==================================================================================================
```

I want to fire a Trigger when there is an update in **tbl_1** but only when the status is 1. If it is not 1, then the trigger wont be fired.

Here is my Trigger Query

```
CREATE TRIGGER audit_before_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl_1
FOR EACH ROW 
if(Status = 1 ) then
 INSERT INTO tbl_audit
 set
  Id=old.Id,            
  Name=old.Name,                   
  Status=old.Status,              
  flag=old.flag,      
  audit_time_stamp=now()
end if;
```

But, **it's always showing an error at `end if;`**. I tried changing the Demiliter, but that didnt work.

Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to fire a Trigger when there is an update in tbl_1 but only when the status is 1. If it is not 1, then the trigger wont be fired.

Trigger is fired always when its action is performed. But the action can be executed only when needed condition is met.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER audit_before_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl_1
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO tbl_audit (Id, Name, Status, flag, audit_time_stamp)
SELECT OLD.Id, OLD.Name, OLD.Status, OLD.flag, now()
WHERE OLD.Status <>= 1; /* or NEW.Status? unclear... */
```

So if old Status value is 1 then none row is inserted else the row with old values are saved into the audit table.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=72d82f29beed143ed6d6ca502638ead1

---

> But, it's always showing an error at `end if;`

Multiple statement code block must be enclosed with BEGIN-END. Each separate statement must be finalized with `;`.

Comment: Using `Begin.... End` still showed the same error at the same place, including `end` now

Comment: @Asish `BEGIN` must be placed  after `FOR EACH ROW`, and `END` must be placed after `end if;`. Also `;` must be placed after `NOW()` for the INSERT query termination.

Comment: I re-wrote the trigger using the syntax that you mentioned, now the error line is shown at `where old.Status=1;`

Comment: @Asish Oops... I have inverted the condition. Fixed. And fiddle added.

Comment: I had to remove `Begin.... End` from the code, because I think it is wrong to use them when there is only one line of code. Now it works

Comment: Btw, what was wrong with my initial method, using `IF THEN ELSE` ? Is that Syntax not valid?

Comment: @Asish *I think it is wrong to use them when there is only one line of code.* `IF - END IF;` is 1st statement. Inner `INSERT` is 2nd statement. BEGIN-END is compulsory.